# How to Zoom and Pan SWF file in Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, zooming

I need to pan and zoom swf file . I have work with [adobe's zoom component](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/samples/fig_panzoom.html). But it work only with images.

My requirement is zoom the specified area of swf and set centrally when I drag and drop a 
rectangle to the swf file.

Have any open source api available for doing this. or please give any useful information.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

U can use native Gesture-events. Catch them from the Stage or any other instance of InteractiveObject class.
e.g.:

```actionscript
anyYourInteractiveObject.addEventListener(GestureEvent.GESTURE_TWO_FINGER_TAP, twoTapHandler);
```

or

```
stage.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_ZOOM, zoomGestureHandler);
```